# Is there a more efficient way to prevent a a line of code from being executed based on past script executions?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

**Explanation**

My **python** script is a *scheduled task* checking for a certain result. If that result comes out to true, then no message is sent, if that result comes out to false, then a message is sent (*one line of code*) notifying the recipients.

This is running every couple of minutes using the *task scheduler*.

If the result is false, and a message is sent, I would like to **prevent any sort of spam** by not sending the message again every time the script is executed, thus not executing a *line of code* based on past script executions.

**What I Tried**

Now my solution is that once the 'result is false' message is sent, a simple text file is created in the same directory. If the script runs again and the result is false (again) then it would check if the text file exists. If the text file exists, then that means the 'result is false' message has already been released to the recipient. So, it would not send another one.

If the result is set back to true, then the text file is deleted from the directory, so any future false results can be notified to the recipient.

**Question**

Is there a more efficient way of checking whether a certain line of code has been executed in the past without creating a text file?

Comment: Text file (or any other form of storage) is the way to go. It's cheap and reliable, especially if the script runs only every couple minutes.

Comment: There is no way for your script to know what past executions did unless that data was saved on disk. So, your solution (using the text file) is completely valid.